# How to sort a list of maps based on values inside the maps in Dart?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have a list that I want to sort. That list contains multiple maps with key and values.
Basically, it looks like this:

```
class MyObject{
  DateTime date;
  String myText;

  MyObject({required this.date, required this.myText});
}

void main()
{
  MyObject obj1 = MyObject(date: DateTime.now(), myText: "abc");
  MyObject obj2 = MyObject(date: DateTime.now(), myText: "bcd");

  // just a demo, in reality there are more unordered dates
  var myList = [{"obj": obj1 , "etc": "someEntry1"}, {"obj": obj2, "etc": "someEntry2"}];
}
```

I want to sort the list based on ascending dates in the maps and tried the following line of code to sort the list:

```
myList.sort((a, b) => a['obj'].date.compareTo(b['obj'].date));
```

But I ended up getting the following error:
[image]

How to solve the sorting problem?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't replicate the exact same error. But you can make it sort, as I think you want, by making a small adjustment.

Since your map is mixing datatypes, then you have to help dart know that the object under the key "obj" is of type MyObject. Check this [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=915b2132fa7401fe2c85821d9afcc135) where I've added a cast.

This is what I've changed:

```
myList.sort((a, b) => (a['obj']! as MyObject).date.compareTo((b['obj']! as MyObject).date));
```

Note that you might want to do something safer than just assuming that `x['obj']` will not be null...